# Group Policy Printers only deployes at first login on RDP

Tags: group-policy, rdp

I'm struggling to get Group Policy Printers to deploy on our RDP server 2008 r2.

They all deploy fine the first time users logon, but hereafter no printers deploy.
If I make changes to the GPO, the printers will deploy again at next logon, but after that they will disappear again. What am I doing wrong??
Any help greatly appreciated!!

Best regards,
Steffen.

Comment: How do you deploy this? Are you using GPP? Please add some screenshots from the policy.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Please read [How do I ask a good question](//$SITEURL/help/how-to-answer) and try to rewrite your question so that it matches the site quidelines. Include the following: What have you tried? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead? What does your config look like? Do you have any log entries from the times it didn't work as expected?

Comment: Yes, I am using GPP - screenshots coming up...

Comment: https://s20.postimg.org/5gihr85rh/Capture.png

Comment: [GPO Settings](https://s20.postimg.org/azq4t3lm5/Capture.png)

Comment: the setting seem ok, please select ´run in user context', double click the printer and check second tab for the settings. let me know if it help

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve this problem by adding the following option to our terminal server GPO:

COMPUTER POLICY\ADMINISTRATIVE TEMPLATES\SYSTEM\GROUP POLICY\Printers preference extension policy processing: Process even if the Group Policy objects have not changed.

Not sure if that is the best solution, but it works for now. :)